# Karma disconnects when using ddescribe in jasmine tests

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I receive the following message:

`Chrome 37.0.2062 (Mac OS X 10.9.4): Executed 7 of 557 (1 FAILED) (skipped 218) DISCONNECTED (2.03 secs / 0.072 secs)`

Using jasmine 0.1.5 and karma 0.12.21

The block in question has a ddescribe to select just it. The tests persist and update with changes if I run all of them or if the tests pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem with my unit tests (Jasmine 2.0.0 and Karma 0.12.23) and a coworker mentioned a bug with istanbul/karma-coverage. When I turn off the `coverage` preprocessor in karma the disconnect problem went away and my stack traces were fixed as well. If you update your karma.conf `preprocessors` block to remove/comment any `coverage` while writing tests this should make things all good.

```
//karma.conf.js ...

preprocessors: {
    // 'js/**.js':['coverage'] // disable coverage to debug tests
},

...
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to stop it from disconnecting

Comment: This didn't worked for me. Switching the browsers from Chrome to PhantomJS worked instead!